# update table rows where column values are different from another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables with the same schema, one is just a table that data gets bulk loaded into and the other is my live table.  I want to update the live table from the uploaded table where the rows are different.  I think I am pretty close here but where would my UPDATE actually come into play?

This gives me my updated rows that actually have changes I want to push into my live table:

```
SELECT USC.* FROM UpdateStagingCustomers AS USC
JOIN StagingCustomers AS SC
ON USC.CustomerNumber = SC.CustomerNumber
AND USC.ManufacturerID = SC.ManufacturerID
WHERE USC.ManufacturerID=18 AND SC.ManufacturerID = 18
    AND USC.CustomerNumber IN(
        SELECT CustomerNumber FROM StagingCustomers WHERE ManufacturerID=18
    )
    AND 
    (
    USC.Address1 <> SC.Address1 OR
    USC.Address2 <> SC.Address2 OR
    USC.AuthorizedDealer <> SC.AuthorizedDealer OR
    USC.City <> SC.City
    )
```

Comment: `WHERE USC.ManufacturerID=18 AND SC.ManufacturerID = 18
    AND USC.CustomerNumber IN(
        SELECT CustomerNumber FROM StagingCustomers WHERE ManufacturerID=18
    )`
Does this produce different results than just USC.ManufacturerID = 18?  You are joining on CustomerNumber and ManufacturerID, so it appears to be redundant.  More do your question, which table are you trying to update?

Comment: added that as a safe guard I guess, probably not needed.  I am trying to update the StagingCustomers table with the values from the UpdateStagingTables

Comment: Then David's answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this SQL Statement will do the job, but you might want to test it in a rolled back transaction.

```
UPDATE StagingCustomers 
SET Address1 = USC.Address1, 
    Address2 = USC.Address2, 
    AuthorizedDealer = USC.AuthorizedDealer,
    City = USC.City
FROM UpdateStagingCustomers AS USC
JOIN StagingCustomers AS SC
ON USC.CustomerNumber = SC.CustomerNumber
AND USC.ManufacturerID = SC.ManufacturerID
WHERE USC.ManufacturerID=18 AND SC.ManufacturerID = 18
    AND USC.CustomerNumber IN(
        SELECT CustomerNumber FROM StagingCustomers WHERE ManufacturerID=18
    )
    AND 
    (
    USC.Address1 <> SC.Address1 OR
    USC.Address2 <> SC.Address2 OR
    USC.AuthorizedDealer <> SC.AuthorizedDealer OR
    USC.City <> SC.City
    )
```

Comment: don;t I need a where clause on my UPDATE StagingCustomers?

Comment: SQL is smart enough that it sees you are selecting from StagingCustomers and will update the records selected.  Just a note, I think it is more clear to have the `FROM` table match the `UPDATE` table, but it will produce the same result.

Comment: As long as the FROM clause gets the records you are looking for in a SELECT statement, that same FROM clause can go into an UPDATE and the table that will get changed in the one listed after the UPDATE.